# How to reshape the input to put in Conv2d layers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use Conv2d to train my model, and  i have problem/ with the input of Conv2d layers. How can i reshape it to put into Conv2d

- I am building model for classify voice accent, and using CNN. I am using Conv2d for this problem.
- The shape of:
               X_train: (78952, 26) (26 features)
  X_test : (2574, 26)
- I reshape it as (78952, 13, 2 , 1), (2574, 13, 2, 1) it ran well. But I cannot use kernel such as (3x3), (7x7), ....

How can I change the right input to put in Conv2d layers ?

Comment: to start off, when you have single dimension features, why can't you try conv1d ? or am i missing some information why conv2d was tried?

Comment: Great idea, i didn't think about it. I will try it now

Comment: yes. go ahead with conv1d and hopefully you get better results. play around with the strides ,  filters accordingly to achieve decent performance.